# How to reinitialize dynamic Semantic UI Search Dropdown

Tags: semantic-ui

How can I reinitialize selectdd2 dropdown option on change of selectddl dropdown? Anyone can help me on this?

**For example :** If we select country the corresponding states will be loaded in second dropdown.

HTML Code

```
 <select class="ui search selection dropdown dropdown-spinner" id="selectdd1">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
 </select>
 <select class="ui search selection dropdown dropdown-spinner" id="selectdd2">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need reinitialize your dropdown input , all you need is to change options dynamically in `select` element *(state)* when the value of your first `select` element *(country)* is changed ,by listening  to `onchange` event.
Here is a [simple demo example](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/PKqWEr?editors=1010) , and here is an [example with Semantic-UI countries flags](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/brdBKO?editors=1010)

Comment: This is working fine in chrome. But this is not working in safari. To work in safari any changes needs to be done?

Comment: Also I can populate the options. But unable to select the items only in safari